# How do I get the elements of a list within a given percentile range?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, math

I am trying to iterate over a list of elements that satisfy my
percentile range without using numPy. I am approaching the problem with a simple for-loop. The answer I am receiving is of all the elements that I want but it is being repeated. Where am I lacking?

```
yos = [('student3', 12),
         ('student4', 14),
         ('student9', 35),
         ('student6', 43),
         ('student1', 45),
         ('student7', 47),
         ('student5', 48),
         ('student2', 78),
         ('student10', 80),
         ('student8', 98)]
        
for si in range(25, 76):
    y = len(yos)*(si/100)
    y1 = int(y+.5)
    if yos[y1-1] in yos:
    print(yos[y1-1])
```

**Wanted output:**

```
    ('student9', 35)
    ('student6', 43)
    ('student1', 45)
    ('student7', 47)
    ('student5', 48)
```

**Received output:**

```
('student9', 35)
('student9', 35)
('student9', 35)
('student9', 35)
('student9', 35)
('student9', 35)
('student9', 35)
('student9', 35)
('student9', 35)
('student9', 35)
('student6', 43)
('student6', 43)
('student6', 43)
('student6', 43)
('student6', 43)
('student6', 43)
('student6', 43)
('student6', 43)
('student6', 43)
('student6', 43)
('student1', 45)
('student1', 45)
('student1', 45)
('student1', 45)
('student1', 45)
('student1', 45)
('student1', 45)
('student1', 45)
('student1', 45)
('student1', 45)
('student7', 47)
('student7', 47)
('student7', 47)
('student7', 47)
('student7', 47)
('student7', 47)
('student7', 47)
('student7', 47)
('student7', 47)
('student7', 47)
('student5', 48)
('student5', 48)
('student5', 48)
('student5', 48)
('student5', 48)
('student5', 48)
('student5', 48)
('student5', 48)
('student5', 48)
('student5', 48)
('student2', 78)
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Step through your code and narrow down the problem into a [mre]. 
Then ask a specific question. _"Why is my code doing this"_ is [too broad for Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/843953)
Please also take the [tour], read [ask] and [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Can you think of a mathematical rule that tells you the smallest and largest indices into the list that you should use? If you have those, can you think of a way to just iterate over that section of the list?

Comment: Thank you Pranav. I'll take note. I'm new to the website but I'll remember going through your links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation results in duplicate values.

```py
y = len(yos)*(si/100)
y1 = int(y+.5)
```

y1 will be the same value for multiple iterations.  y=2.6, y=2.7, y=2.8, y=2.9 all convert to 3 when you add .5 and convert it to an int.

One option would be to create a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) of indices, then just print out the values at those indices.

Something like:

```py
import math


yos = [('student3', 12),
       ('student4', 14),
       ('student9', 35),
       ('student6', 43),
       ('student1', 45),
       ('student7', 47),
       ('student5', 48),
       ('student2', 78),
       ('student10', 80),
       ('student8', 98)]


set_of_indices = set([int(math.floor(len(yos) * (si / 100))) for si in range(25, 76)])

for y in set_of_indices:
    print(yos[y])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
z = [('student3', 12),
         ('student4', 14),
         ('student9', 35),
         ('student6', 43),
         ('student1', 45),
         ('student7', 47),
         ('student5', 48),
         ('student2', 78),
         ('student10', 80),
         ('student8', 98)]
        
for si in range(25, 75,10):
    y = (len(z)*si)/100
    y1 = int(y+.5)
    if z[y1-1] in z: print(z[y1-1])
```

Try the code here

It's in fact the int() function that created the problem. so the solution was to add `10` as a third parameter in range: `range(25, 75,10)`
To understand more, please see the `.range()` function documentation

You've gotta also make the range be between `25` and `75`, not `76`... So you don't have a problem with .int()